# Confirmar cerrar ventana en JDialog

Tags: java, jdialog

Quiero tener una **confirmación al cerrar** un `JDialog`, lo hago de la misma manera que si fuera un JFrame, pero en este caso **si pulso "NO", se me cierra de igual manera.**

En archivos JFrame me funciona pero en JDialog, no.

¿Por qué?

**Código:**

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JDialog{
    public Login(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);

        //Código para confirmar el cierre de la ventana principal.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", 
                        "Gestor de clientes", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: JOptionPane tiene otras constantes que tienen el valor 0 (Yes) que son más adecuadas para cada tipo de JOptionPane, en este caso de Yes o NO, existe la constante YES_OPTION que queda mucho mejor para tu tipo de JOptionPane, aclara mucho más el código para otros programadores, incluso para tí mismo dentro de X tiempo.

Comment: A mí si me funciona tu código. Yo uso OpenJDK 14.0.1

Comment: A mi en un JDialog no.

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que pruebes a eliminar la línea: super(parent, modal); Luego si quieres puedes establecer la propiedad modal con el método setModal, aunque no he encontrado el setter para el parent. Ese super es la única diferencia significativa con respecto a la clase ejemplo que te he puesto en otra respuesta.

Comment: Lo probé y no es eso. No sé porque en el JFrame si me funciona pero en el JDialog no.

Comment: Prueba la clase que te puse de ejemplo en la respuesta que te puse. A ver si a tí te funciona o no. A mí si me funciona tu código en esa clase. Si no te funciona, es cosa de version jre

Comment: @Jesús Me funciona tu código pero no entiendo porque en mi caso no...

Comment: setVisible al final? Siempre me dijeron que fuese siempre lo último.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí si me funciona ese invento de no hacer nada si se cierra, y mandar cerrar según la respuesta al JOptionPane.

Puedes hacer tus pruebas con la siguiente clase diseñada para hacer pruebas de eventos de ventana:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EventosDeVentana{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Ventana().addWindowListener(new MarcoEventoVentana());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Ventana extends JDialog{
    public Ventana() {
        setBounds(300,300,300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MarcoEventoVentana implements WindowListener{

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Se ha abierto la ventana");
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Se está cerrando la ventana");
         if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", 
         "Gestor de clientes", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
     System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Ventana minimizada");
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que si no entra al `if` debes frenar la propagación del evento usando el método [AWTEvent#consume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#consume()).

El código debe quedar así

```
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", 
                        "Gestor de clientes", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE){
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                // No necesitamos un else porque si ejecuta el código dentro del if
                // se terminará el proceso y no llegará nunca aquí
                evt.consume()
            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué ese código en un JFrame me sirve y en un JDialog, no?

Comment: Su código me da un error de: consume() has protected access in AWTEvent

Comment: ¿Por qué me sale error en la línea evt.consume?

Comment: La verdad no sé porqué funciona con un `JFrame` y no con un `JDialog` hace mucho años que no uso SWING o AWT. Quizás con los `JDialog` debes definir `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` para liego capturar el evento y hacer lo que necesites.